# How to insert a value with '&' in sqlplus with python

Tags: python, oracle, insert, sqlplus

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import *
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import os

connectString = 'SYSTEM/mediadot123'

def runSqlQuery(sqlCommand, connectString):
   session = Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', connectString], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
   session.stdin.write(sqlCommand)
   return session.communicate()


session = Popen(['C:\\app\khize_000\product\\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\sqlplus.exe','-S','hr/hr'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = session.communicate()

sqlCommand = "set define off;"
queryResult, errorMessage = runSqlQuery(sqlCommand, connectString)
print queryResult

titledb = "retrieved from somewhere else with & in it"

sqlCommand = "insert into food(title) values ('" + str(titledb.encode('utf-8')) + "');"
queryResult, errorMessage = runSqlQuery(sqlCommand, connectString)
print queryResult
```

I saw that 'set define off' query on oracle website but its not working for me with the code. It is working in the command line but not here. It gives me the following error:

> Bacon, Potato & Egg Breakfast Casserole
>
> Enter value for egg:
>
> SP2-0546: User requested Interrupt or EOF detected.

Comment: `import cx_Oracle` then use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set define off` command does not persist between SQLPlus sessions.  Each time you call `runSQLQuery` you are opening a new instance of SQLPlus.  You would need to execute `set define off` in the same session as the actual insert command for it to have the desired effect.

If you are confident that you won't ever need the substitution functionality in this context, you could send it as a command to SQLPlus in the `runSQLQuery` function, before sending the statement passed as a parameter.

You could redesign your entire logic to keep a single SQLPlus session open and write multiple commands to it.

Or, you could locate a proper library for connecting directly to Oracle from Python, rather than executing an external SQLPlus process.

Comment: sqlCommand = "set define off; insert into food(title) values ('" + str(titledb.encode('utf-8')) + "');"  
queryResult, errorMessage = runSqlQuery(sqlCommand, connectString)  
print queryResult  

I tried it this way too, but still it gives the same error.

Comment: Sure, because you are still sending a single line, and SQLplus parses the line for substitution variables first, before trying to actually execute it, and that is what causes the issue.  You need to write code that emulates how you would do it interactively - type "set define off", press Enter, then type the insert command.

Comment: i tried this:  
`sqlcommand = "set define off;\n insert into......"`  
And it worked.. thanku soo much